# Probability of secretary making 4 or more errors on a page

Tags: probability, statistics

I have this problem, and I want to figure out how to do it, or at least figure out the subject that it deals with.

> A secretary who only does word processing makes $2$ errors per page when typing. What is the probability that in the next page she makes $4$ or more errors?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean that the secretary makes an *average* of two errors per page.

Usually, errors of this type are modelled using the **Poisson** distribution with parameter $\lambda$ equal to the mean number of errors per "unit," in this case page.

So if $X$ is the number of errors in a given page, our Poisson model gives
$$\Pr(X=k)=e^{-2}\frac{2^k}{k!}.$$

The probability of $4$ or more errors is $1$ minus the probability of $3$ or fewer errors. And
$$\Pr(X\le 3)=\sum_{k=0}^3 e^{-2}\frac{2^k}{k!}.$$

**Remark:** At best, the Poisson model will fit reality only modestly well.

Comment: Wow! So fast! So is that the answer for the problem?

Comment: I don't know whether you are expected to produce a "decimal." I think the probability of $4$ or more errors will turn out to be about $0.143$.